# Extract CentOS mirror domain names using sed

Tags: sed, centos6

I'm trying to extract a list of CentOS domain names only from http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6.4&arch=x86_64&repo=os
Truncating prefix "http://" and "ftp://" to the first "/" character only resulting a list of

yum.phx.singlehop.com
mirror.nyi.net
bay.uchicago.edu
centos.mirror.constant.com
mirror.teklinks.com
centos.mirror.netriplex.com
centos.someimage.com
mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
mirrors.tummy.com

I searched stackoverflow for the sed method but I'm still having trouble.

I tried doing this with sed
`curl "http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6.4&arch=x86_64&repo=os" | sed '/:\/\//,/\//p'`
but doesn't look like it is doing anything. Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

`curl "http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6.4&arch=x86_64&repo=os" | sed -e 's?.*://??' -e 's?/.*??'`

Your `sed` was completely wrong:

- `/x/,/y/` is a *range*. It selects multiple *lines*, from a line matching `/x/` until a line matching `/y/`
- The `p` command prints the selected range

Since all lines match both the start and end pattern you used, you effectively selected all lines. And, since `sed` echoes the input by default, the `p` command results in duplicated lines (all lines printed twice).

In my fix:

- I used `s???` instead of `s///` because this way I didn't need to escape all the `/` in the patterns, so it's a bit more readable this way
- I used two expressions with the `-e` flag:

  - `s?.*://??` matches everything up until `://` and replaces it with nothing
  - `s?/.*??` matches everything from `/` until the end replaces it with nothing
- The two expressions are executed in the given order
- In modern versions of `sed` you can omit `-e` and separate the two expressions with `;`. I stick to using `-e` because it's more portable.